# Makerbot Replicator 2 Halts during print

Tags: makerbot

I am running a MakerBot Replicator 2. During the print, the printer just stops executing and I am running out of ways to troubleshoot.

After restarting, I can load and extrude filament.

I have replaced the SD card, and even borrowed one from another working replicator, and the freeze still occurs.

Likewise, I've regenerated the x3g file, and that did not work.

The panel does not freeze, I can cancel the print during the freeze.

I've made sure Z pause is off. It tends freezes randomly on the first layer.

In general, it looks as though the print is "in progress" but not making progress (Timer ticks up, % completed does not)

Does anyone have any idea as to what could be causing the problem?

Comment: Ouch. If I had to guess something is overheating on your controller board. Probably need new electronics. But that is a complete guess.. The rep 2.. I think you can take that guy apart. Verify all the connections. Put back together.

Comment: You got it, I'm not sure which connection it was, but after hunting down all the connectors and giving them a firm press, the issue was corrected.

Comment: Are you running the most current firmware version?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options. First your board could be overheating etc. That is harder to verify without some overpriced replacements. So to start lets take everything apart (photo and labeling is Strongly recommended). Then simply put it back together. Hopefully it is just a loose connection.

Answer (score 1):

By "stops executing" do you mean that the extruder stops extruding but continues to run through the motions? or does the entire machine lock up?

If your extruder stops depositing plastic, then I would suggest checking your settings. Specifically retraction distance, filament diameter (compered with your actual filament diameter)  and temperatures. Sometimes bumping up the extruder temp 5 degrees can fix this issue.

If all that's ok, then I'd suggest possibly swapping your extruder nozzle, if it has a bur inside from manufacturing then this could be causing too much pressure and the nozzle gets clogged.

IF however the extruder gantry freezes up and the z-axis keeps pulling away, I'd suggest calling maker bot directly as this would be more of a serious hardware issue, likely covered under warranty.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

After removing the front panel and the bottom protector plate (the one that protects the controller board) and firmly pressing every connector, the issue corrected itself. It seems that something was loose, and that causes the freeze behavior.

Answer (score -1):

Seems like others have had similar issues: https://www.thingiverse.com/groups/engineering/topic:3849. Their issue was a bit more mechanical than firmware, though. I hope this helps!

You might also want to check the software you're using to slice the file. Sometimes the software doesn't slice the file properly, which causes problems mid-print.